# Excel Conditional Formatting based on multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have this data as example

[Excel Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08M8c.png)

[image]

How to do conditional formatting so that if I put another data on the **same date** and **another city** (for example on 30/10/2019 to Paris) and then I choose **car**, it will be highlighted because the car had been used on that dates to Tokyo.

But if its already on different dates then it does not highlight.

Thank you

Comment: Use conditional formatting by user formula, use COUNTIFS() in it (eq by date and vehicle and neq by city), apply colouring if its value is not zero.

Comment: How to make it equal to the whole column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data occupies columns A:C starting from row 2 (header - row 1).

- Select column C
- Open Conditional formatting - Create rule
- Select category Use formula
- Insert the condition `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,C:C,C1,B:B,"<>" & B1)>0`
- Specify format (for example, set background color to red)
- Save and apply

Now enter one more row with Date=30/10/2019, City=London and Vehicle=Car.

The cells in the Vehicle column will be colored - in newly inserted line and in lines 2..4.

[image]

Comment: Thank you its working